# EditText - How to set default text in android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an android application which people will enter their bills.
I have an EditText which people enter the amount.

What I want to do is that for example If a person enters "2" it should be converted automatically to "0.02". Then if he/she wants to enter 22$ he should push 2, 2, 0 and 0 buttons. It will be like that "22.00". How can I manage to do that using EditText. Can you give me some ideas guys?

Here is the related code pieces :

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/enter_amount"
            android:singleLine="true" />



            EditText payment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
            if (payment.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                total_amount =Integer.parseInt(payment.getText().toString()) ;
            }
```

Comment: Yes, get the int value, then divide it by 100 and then update the EditText, on Enter keypress for example.

Comment: @Stacks28 - `android:hint="@string/entered_amount_will_be_divided_by_100_lol"`

Comment: Add to the layout also `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`, because you're going to visualize `double` values :)

Answer (score 3):

```
EditText payment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
payment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             total_amount =Integer.parseInt(s) ;
               payment.setText(""+(total_amount/100));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to use textWatcher like this :

```
payment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `addTextChangedListener()`

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText payment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        if (payment.getText().toString().length() > 0){
        double total_amount =Double.parseDouble(payment.getText().toString()) ;
        String amm = String.valueOf(total_amount/100);
        payment.setText(amm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `TextWatcher` in order to alter their input as they enter it. Here is an example:

```
TextWatcher paymentWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            //Do your calculations here
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
    };

    payment.addTextChangedListener(paymentWatcher);
```